# How to show difference of new Pull Request and an existing Pull Request?

Tags: git, rebase

I currently have a PR that has not been merged with the Master branch.

And I just created a new PR, and I would like to ONLY see the difference between this new PR and the original PR above.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I tried to rebase but managed to mess things up quite badly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try this [link](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-comparing-branches-in-pull-requests)

Comment: Thanks for the link @devMe, I still couldn't quite get how to do it even after going through the content though.

Answer (score -1):

I usually track changes through the server. For example, on GitLab. There is an opportunity to see the commit history in a convenient way.

Comment: The OP uses the term "PR" so wen can guess [s]he uses Github.

Comment: Indeed. But it's good to know.